# Change x-axis ticks to custom strings

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I want to change the x-axis ticklabels to custom strings, but the following does not work. How can I set the ticklabels to `["one", "two", "three"]`?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def pushButtonClicked(self):
        code = self.lineEdit.text()
       
       
        x=["one","two","three"]
        l=[1,2,3]
        y=[2,3,4]
        ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
       
        print(1)
        
        ax.plot(l, y, label='DeadPopulation')
        ax.xticks(l,x)
        print(IntroUI.g_sortArrayDeadcnt)
      
        ax.legend(loc='upper right') 
        ax.grid() 
        self.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: change post title to something like 'how can I apply string type in Pyqt matplotlib.plot'

Comment: @Raj Damani , I  solve this problem right now. Reason is, I didn't use function 'set_xticks' . Thank you

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I assume you just want to set the ticks to be equal to `['one', 'two', 'three']`?

To do this, you need to use `set_xticks()` and `set_xticklabels()`:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def pushButtonClicked(self):
        code = self.lineEdit.text()


        x=["one","two","three"]
        l=[1,2,3]
        y=[2,3,4]
        ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        print(1)

        ax.plot(l, y, label='DeadPopulation')

        # Set the tick positions
        ax.set_xticks(l)
        # Set the tick labels
        ax.set_xticklabels(x)

        print(IntroUI.g_sortArrayDeadcnt)

        ax.legend(loc='upper right') 
        ax.grid() 
        self.canvas.draw()
```

## Minimal example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, ax = plt.subplots()

x = ['one', 'two', 'three']
l = [1, 2, 3]
y = [2, 3, 4]

ax.plot(l,y)
ax.set_xticks(l)
ax.set_xticklabels(x)

plt.show()
```

Here is how it would look like:

[image: Plot with custom x-axis ticklabels]

Answer (score 2):

### New in matplotlib 3.5.0

Use the `labels` param of [`ax.set_xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html) to set ticks and labels simultaneously:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [10, 0, 4]
l = ['one', 'two', 'three']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_xticks(x, labels=l)
#                ^^^^^^
```

Note that [`plt.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) has always had this functionality:

```
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xticks(x, labels=l)
```

Using [`ax.set_xticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html) is now discouraged, but the method will remain for backward compatibility.

[image]